# How to add a dir to fpath

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

I'm using zsh and prezto.

I've adding the following line at the end of my `.zshrc`

```
fpath=(/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions $fpath)
```

But unfortunately, the functions defined in this folder seems ignored by the completion.

Here is the content of the folder :

```
~ ❯❯❯ ls /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions
_docker                 _git                    _hub                    _ponysay                _ponysay-tool           _ponythink              git-completion.bash     git-flow-completion.zsh
```

And I have no completion on docker command

Answer (score 4):

Completion functions are automatically loaded on first use, but they have to be noticed first. Merely changing `fpath` doesn't cause the files containing functions to be read in order to notice the functions. This is done by the `compinit` function.

The easy way to get your completion functions noticed would be to modify `fpath` earlier in your `.zshrc`, before the call to `compinit`.

As the `fpath` traversal is deep inside the `compinit`, I don't think there's a better way to get a directory taken into account than running `compinit` (again).

Comment: `compinit` creates a cache file regardless, `-d` allows you to specify a filename yourself. otherwise `${ZDOTDIR:-$HOME}/.zcompdump` is used.